# Why is the Radon–Nikodym theorem important in probability?

Tags: probability, derivatives

I was reading [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) and came across the following statement:

> The Radon–Nikodym theorem essentially states that, under certain conditions, any measure ν can be expressed in this way with respect to another measure μ on the same space. The function  f  is then called the Radon–Nikodym derivative and is denoted by {\displaystyle {\tfrac {d\nu }{d\mu }}}{\displaystyle {\tfrac {d\nu }{d\mu }}}.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) An important application is in probability theory, leading to the probability density function of a random variable.

I am trying to understand why this important - i.e., why is the Radon–Nikodym theorem important in defining the probability density function of a random variable?

In the courses I have taken in statistics/probability (engineering), we were always shown the definition of a probability distribution (of a random variable) without any mention of the Radon-Nikodym theorem. I would have never even known that such a theorem existed, let alone that such a theorem would be so important in defining the probability density of a random variable.

Why is the Radon-Nikodym theorem so important in defining the probability density of a random variable? Is it really that important that it can not be defined without this theorem?

Comment: I don't know that it's satisfying, but the motivation for that statement *in that Wikipedia plot summary* can probably be found in the first paragraph of the [Applications subsection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Applications).

Comment: You don't need Radon-Nikodym to define a density [with respect to Lebesgue measure] but it provides a nice framework/notation to talk about densities in the theory.  More important applications appear when one is changing probability measures (e.g. using Girsanov's theorem to solve problems in financial mathematics)

Comment: You can learn about continuous-valued RVs without referring to Radon-Nikodym, but it's useful in concluding that (for example) the probability of the RV being between 0 and 1 is the integral of the PDF therein.

Comment: It's not so much a question of defining a density as proving that a density exists when the distribution is absolutely continuous.  Non-rigorous probability and statistics courses tend to tacitly assume random variables are either discrete or have a density, simply ignoring other possibilities.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your kind replies! I recently posted another question - if someone has time, can you please take a look?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506330/different-types-of-markov-chains thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The theorem isn't necessary for defining the density of a random variable. After all, any measurable nonnegative function that integrates to $1$ is a density. One major application of the Radon-Nikodym theorem is to prove the existence of the conditional expectation. Really, the existence of conditional expectation is very much related to the Radon Nikodym theorem, and in fact can be used to prove the theorem. See [https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) for details.

Comment: @ Mason: thank you so much for your answer! I recently posted a question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506330/different-types-of-markov-chains .... if you have time, can you please take a look at it? thank you so much! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506330/different-types-of-markov-chains

Answer (score 3):

I think, given the background that you mentioned that you have, understanding the Radon-Nikodym Theorem is not necessarily going to bring you any clarity in it's connection with Probability. But you can think about it as an analogue of the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

> Suppose that we have $f(x)$, a continuous function on a closed interval $[a,b]$. Then we can construct an anti-derivative for $f(x)$ via
> $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \; dt$$ for all values of $x \in [a,b]$.

You can think about "measure" as a fancy mathematical term for "length." So given any two points $x \leq y$ in $[a,b]$ you can determine the length of the interval between those two values as $y-x$. This new function $F(x)$ gives you a way of defining another length on $[a,b]$. You could calculate another distance between those two points as $$F(y) - F(x).$$

If you get down into the gritty details, this new "measure" of length has many of the same properties as the old "measure." But it tells us something different, it can tell us about the probability of an event occurring. The Radon-Nikodym theorem just states that we can express the second measure using the first (but there are many mathematical details that are being brushed under the rug in that explanation).

**DISCLAIMER:** I am not an analyst and have most likely forgotten many key details about the Radon-Nykodym Theorem, but I hope this helped at least a bit.

Comment: @ dbossaller: thank you so much for your answer! I recently posted a question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506330/different-types-of-markov-chains ... if you have time, can you please take a look at it? thank you so much!